# Best way to block a user from clicking somewhere else than current frame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So, I was wondering, how to block user from exiting or switching to another JFrame in application? I don't have the code yet, but this picture should be clear enough:
[image]

Those gray squares are JFrames. Frame with number 2 on it is on top, and I want it do stay that way until I programmatically close it. Any action like clicking on frame with number 1 or trying to do anything out of frame with number 2, should result in focusing on frame with number 2 again.

Step with logic in frame 2 is essential, so I want to make sure the user will fill in the from in the frame.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can restrict focus to a given window if it extends from `JDialog` (and set to be `modal`. You can't restrict a user from clicking anywhere else outside your application. This assumes that the windows are all generated from the same JVM

Comment: See [How to use dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, I should switch from extending JFrame to JDialog? And, yes, I need to restrict focusing on another window.

Comment: *"I should switch from extending JFrame to JDialog?"* The code should be **using** one `JFrame` and as many `JDialog` windows as the app. needs, but there is likely no good reason to be **extending** either class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, use a **modal** dialog that specifies the frame as owner, and the user will not be able to access the frame until the dialog is dismissed.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class BlockUserFromFrame {

    BlockUserFromFrame() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Try to access frame!");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel l = new JLabel("Access frame after dialog disappears!");
        l.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(50, 100, 50, 100));
        f.add(l);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);

        // use a constructor that allows us to specify a parent and modality
        JDialog d = new JDialog(f, true);
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Dismiss dialog to access frame!");
        l1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 100, 10, 100));
        d.add(l1);
        d.pack();
        d.setLocationRelativeTo(f);
        d.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            BlockUserFromFrame o = new BlockUserFromFrame();
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```